# magento2 - How to render or use custom html element for attribute in edit admin form of product?

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, product-attribute, renderer

I want render one of attribute in edit admin form of product use my custom html, ex: name, display link to view product page and input edit together.
If anyone know, please advice.